# difference between the types of initialization of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the difference between the two :

*first :*

```
ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

*second :*

```
ArrayList linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or is there any difference ?

Comment: the first is perfectly fine and the second will give a warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

uses generics to ensure type safety.

```
ArrayList linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

doesn't. As @BruceMartin points out, this means that the lines

```
linkList.add(0);
String element = (String) linkList.get(0);
```

gives a **compile time error** in the first case, but fails **at runtime** with the second declaration.

As another example, to `get()` a `String` from the two alternatives, the second variant would require a cast:
*first:*

```
String element = linkList.get(0);
```

*second:*

```
String element = (String) linkList.get(0);
```

Comment: Also type if you use ArrayList<String>, linklist.put(0) will generate a compile time error; if you use ArrayList linkList linklist.put(0) will generate a run time error

Comment: also in the first case `linkList` is of type String and in the second,is of type `Object`

Answer (score 3):

**At compile time:** the first one uses generics, ensures type safety and code readability.

**At runtime:** they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Also in the first case *linkList* is of type String and in the second case is of type *Object*.